# Download the contents of react bootstrap table as CSV or Excel file

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am very new to react so please pardon me if this is a silly question. But I have a react-bootstrap-table that I'm generating of the contents of a giant json nested object from an api call that returns say

```
`a.b.c` with many properties that I dont want to render
```

So we have something along the lines of,

```
`<ReactComponent prop={a.b.c}/> `
```

This generates a react table that I render

where I am doing,
`

```
const PropRow = (p,index) => {

        return(
              <tr key = {index} className='even'>
                  <td> {index + 1} </td>
                  <td>{p.attr1}</td>
                  <td>{p/attr2}</td>
                  {p.attr3.map((object, i) => <td>{object}</td>)}
              </tr>
          )
      }

const PropTable = prop.map((p,index) => PropRow(p,index))
```

`

Returning
`

```
<Table striped bordered hover size="sm" className="table-condensed">
  <tbody>
     {PropTable}
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

`

Im following the tutorial here (https://blog.bitsrc.io/exporting-data-to-excel-with-react-6943d7775a92) and now want to download the table contents as a csv

But the table content is dynamically generated (in a loop and contains only 3 props of this giant nested list of nested json dictionary properties)

Is there a way to just download the final contents of the react-boostrap-table ?

Or do I first need to loop through my data, set the final contents of the table in a state object and just pass that final state only to make this possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-export-csv.html